# How can I access the name/key of a bool (not its value)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, logging, arraylist, key-value

New to coding and working in JavaScript. I'm sure there's a simple way to do this but it's been hard to pinpoint with Google searches.

I'm trying to find a JavaScript function or something of the sort that will find the *name* of a bool in an array (not the bool's value) and return it to me. Also, the bools have to be in an array. I can't make them object keys for my purposes.

Here is a mock example of what I'm trying to do:

JavaScript:

```
function dinnerPreferences(){
  var isChinese = false;
  var isItalian = true;
  var isIndian = false;
  var isHomemade = true;
  var isTakeout = false;

  var dinnerOptions = [isChinese, isItalian, isIndian, isHomemade, isTakeout];
  console.log("Dinner options values: " + dinnerOptions);

  function getPreferences(){
    var wantedDinnerOptions = [];
    // Gather the true values in new array: wantedDinnerOptions
    for(i = 0; i <=dinnerOptions.length; i++){

      if(dinnerOptions[i]){
        wantedDinnerOptions.push(dinnerOptions[i]);
      }
    }
    // Access bool values:
    console.log("Confirm true values: " + wantedDinnerOptions);
    // Access bool length:
    console.log("True value index length: " + wantedDinnerOptions.length)
    // Access bool NAMES(???):
    console.log("Object.keys() doesn't work. What else can I use?");
  }
  getPreferences();
}
  dinnerPreferences();
```

Comment: don't create array, create dictionary and push your variable names as keys, then you can get them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to restructure your `dinnerOptions` array in someway. I'd suggest to transform it to an array of objects, as shown below. So, `dinnerOptions` is still an array but the items in them are more useable/meaningful when present in form of objects.

```js
function dinnerPreferences() {
  const dinnerOptions = [
    { type: "Chinese", availability: false },
    { type: "Italian", availability: true },
    { type: "Indian", availability: false },
    { type: "Homemade", availability: true },
    { type: "Takeout", availability: false },
  ];
  console.log(
    "All dinner options values: " + dinnerOptions.map((opt) => opt.type)
  );

  function getPreferences() {
    const wantedDinnerOptions = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < dinnerOptions.length; i++) {
      if (dinnerOptions[i].availability) {
        wantedDinnerOptions.push(dinnerOptions[i].type);
      }
    }
    console.log("Available dinner options: " + wantedDinnerOptions);
  }
  getPreferences();
}

dinnerPreferences();
```

Also the condition for the `for` loop was incorrect, `i` should be strictly less than `dinnerOptions.length`. And I'd suggest using `let` and `const` instead of `var`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Just to confirm, is there no function that will allow me to do this using an array? Or is it just that making it into an Object and using Object.keys() is best practice?

Comment: @JanaeWelsh It is still an array but the items in the array are objects, so the `type` and `availability` information gets associated together.